# How are timeout blocking calls implemented inside Java classes like Socket

Tags: java, io, timeout

There are many APIs in Java that support `blockingcall(timeout)` like Socket, Lock and others. How are these things implemented in Java?

I tried to find out but it lead to native code which is not visible :(

Is similar approach like creating a thread and interrupting it on timeout are used in java at native level? If so then same could have been done at Java level, why use native?

Comment: *"If so then same could have been done at Java level"* probably not as efficiently.

Comment: You _have_ to resort to native code at some point, Java cannot do everything. It just has a standardized behavior for all "low level" classes which all JVMs must comply to, to the best extent possible. Thread creation, for instance, cannot be done by the JVM itself, it has to ask the OS for that.

Comment: I mean is there some way OS does it differently than a usual way that we are used to do?

Comment: @NarendraPathai in quite a few cases, there is no one-to-one mapping between Java classes and OS primitives, which is why there is the JVM inbetween: it smoothes out the differences as much as it can. Generally, you just shouldn't care anyway, and just program for the JVM and not the OS. Which does not prevent you from thoroughly reading the javadoc: when potential discrepancies exist between JVM implementations, they will be mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it lead to native code which is not visible` This usually means it not implemented in Java. Usually it is implemented by the OS. You can gett he source for Linux, but not Windows AFAIK.

Using Java Thread interrupt, doesn't actually interrupt the thread. It just sets a flag which doesn't wake all blocking operations.  This mechanism is not used as it isn't always what you want.